# Why is the voltage across the 30 kohm resistor taken as 6 V? Is it something to do with the fact that it is a floating voltage source?

Tags: operational-amplifier, floating

[image: strong text]

Why is the voltage across the 30 kΩ resistor taken as 6 V? Is it something to do with the fact that it is a floating voltage source?

Comment: But that's not a floating source.

Answer (score 0):

From [OP AMP FAQ](http://www.ee.nmt.edu/%7Ethomas/ee321/op-faq.html#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20golden%20rule,always%20at%20the%20same%20voltage.)

> Q. What is the golden rule of op-amps?
>
> A. The two inputs always at the same voltage.

It can be seen that the non-inverting input is at the same voltage as the negative terminal of the voltage source. Therefore the inverting input is also at this same voltage.

Hence the voltage across the 30 kΩ resistor is the same as the voltage of the voltage source, i.e. 6 V.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why is the voltage across the 30 kΩ resistor taken as 6 V?*

You need to study what is called a "virtual ground" in op-amps: -

[image]

Hence, there is 6 volts across the 30 kΩ resistor.

The interesting voltage is \$x\$ (-2 volts): -

[image]

And, as you should be able to see the voltage at the inverting input is also -2 volts (a "virtual ground").

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the voltage across the 30 kΩ resistor taken as 6 V?

Because the ideal opamp will do whatever is necessary with the output, using the negative feedback, to keep the Vx and Vy nodes at the same potential:

[image]

Since they are at the same potential, the 6V (which you called "floating") appears across the 30K resistor. This means that there are currents flowing through the resistors, which cause voltage drops as follows:

[image]

Note that the voltage across the source and the 30K resistors are obtained by the difference of the potential between their terminals.